# How to map bidirectional @OneToMany and @OneToOne on the same entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two enteties and I want to be able access one of them from another and vise versa (bidirectional). But sometimes when persisting an order as stopLossOrder it's not saved to position. If you have any ideas of how it can be implemented (if it's possible this way or similar) I would be glad to hear.

Later on I want to add more orders to position entity similarly to 'stopLossOrder'

```
@Entity(name = "Position")
@Table(name = "positions")
@Getter @Setter
public class PositionEntity implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "stop_loss_order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private OrderEntity stopLossOrder;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "position",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<OrderEntity> orders = new HashSet<>();

public void setStopLossOrder(OrderEntity stopLossOrder) {
    this.stopLossOrder = stopLossOrder;
    stopLossOrder.setPosition(this);
}

public boolean addOrder(OrderEntity orderEntity) {
    orderEntity.setPosition(this);
    return orders.add(orderEntity);
}

}
```

```
@Entity(name = "Order")
@Table(name = "orders")
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrderEntity implements Serializable {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1462587657644552577L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   private PositionEntity position;
}
```

Persisting:

```
if (orderEntity.getType() == OrderType.STOP_MARKET) {
    positionEntity.setStopLossOrder(orderEntity);
} else {
    boolean isAdded = positionEntity.addOrder(orderEntity);
    if (!isAdded)
        throw new TradeServiceException("Order with id: " + order.getOrderId() + " already added to position.");
}

orderEntity = orderRepository.save(orderEntity);
```

Comment: Just for clarification: `Position.stopLossOrder` has `@OneToOne` so does that mean that there is only one "special" position per order as well? Also do your orders really just have 1 position that can be shared between orders? That looks a little odd to me.

Comment: "sometimes when persisting an order as stopLossOrder it's not saved to position" - one question you need to ask yourself in those cases is: which side of the relation "owns" it? In the case of one-to-many / many-to-one it's the "many" side as this is where the foreign key will be persisted. With bidirectional "one-to-one" you need to pay more attitention not to confuse the system - only if you persist the "owning side" of a relation will it make it's way to the database which means for "stopLossOrder" it would be `Position` and `stopLossOrder` would have to be set.

Comment: @Thomas There are multiple different positions that can be shared or not between orders. For example: order can have a symbol (that can be the same with others orders) and position(symbol is unique per position) using this symbol I can incorporate orders under the specific position